# NextJS getServerSideProps not sending cookies to server during production

Tags: heroku, cookies, next.js, vercel

I use getServerSideProps to fetch data so that it is available to the user immediately when a user clicks on a link. Sometimes, some data is protected and only available to authenticated users, so I'll need to send an HttpOnly cookie containing the user's JWT to confirm if the user is authenticated or not. This is one of the examples:

```js
export const getSession = async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
  return axios
    .get(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + "/auth/user", {
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        Cookie: context.req.headers.cookie!,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => Promise.resolve(response))
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    });
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: { 
        destination: "/login"
      },
      props: {},
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { session.data },
  };
};
```

This works well in development because both my frontend and backend share the same host (localhost).

However, in production, I host my nextjs app on Vercel and my backend on Heroku. Since they now belong to different domains, the ctx object in getServerSideProps no longer has access to the cookies, causing some parts of the website to break. Is there a way to be able to get access to the cookies, or do I need to set up the backend on Heroku as a subdomain of the frontend site?

Comment: Im using it inside getServerSideProps which I pass context to this function from getServerSideProps.

Comment: were you able to figure out it